# What is this pandoc error

Tags: pandoc, conversion

as try to convert html files to PDF ones

```
$ pandoc *.html -s -o Book.pdf
```

it returned this:

```
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories:
```

the pdflatext is of Arch repos

```
$ sudo pacman -Qo pdflatex
/usr/bin/pdflatex is owned by texlive-bin 2021.58686-3

$ sudo pacman -S texlive-bin
warning: texlive-bin-2021.58686-3 is up to date
```

but the error is under which one, it's not identified

```
$ sudo pacman -Qo texmf.cnf kpathsea
error: No package owns texmf.cnf
error: No package owns kpathsea
```

How to fix the correct setting configuration to be working

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more: Which tex distribution do you use? Which directories are listed in your warning message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install `texlive-core` in your system

```
$ pacman -F texmf.cnf

extra/texlive-core 2021.58710-2 (texlive-most) [installed]
    etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
    usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!